# Best way to cancel "hammer beating wall" noise

Tags: acoustics

I live very near a bulding contruction site, so the "hammer beating wall" noise is a constant in my daylife for the next one year and half (when the building construction will be finished).

In order to cancel the hammer noise, I use a 40 mm headphone with fan noise playing in medium to high volume (I mean, not low volume, but not maximum volume). (My headset doesn't have noise-canceling feature by the way.)

I ask:

1 - Based on Acoustics Science, is this the best way to cancel a "hammer beating wall" noise?

2 - Is there any other frequency, or combinations of frequencies, which I could build using a software, which would be the perfect match for canceling hammer noise? I mean, even better than fan noise frequencies?

Hearing a loud fan noise with headphones is not that nice thing, but is way better than the hammer.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Re, "...perfect match for cancelling...noise." That is, in fact, exactly what noise cancelling headsets _do._ But there's a catch. The perfect signal to cancel the noise is _different_ at every different point where you want the noise cancelled.  The perfect signal for your left ear is different from the perfect signal for your right ear. Noise cancelling headsets have built-in microphones—one or more for each ear—that they use to determine the "perfect" signal. If you can replicate that, then you will have built yourself a pair of noise cancelling headphones.  Cheaper to buy them though!

Comment: P.S.: Cheap solution: First, wear [foam earplugs](https://www.amazon.com/Earplugs-Reusable-Silicone-Sleeping-Protection/dp/B07DK9RLCL/). Then, put your headphones on over the earplugs. With the earplugs in, you'll have to turn the music up louder than normal to achieve a comfortable listening level. That means that the ratio of the music loudness to the annoying noise loudness will be much better.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Solomon. I already use foam earplugs, I forgot to say that, I am sorry. Ok, I will follow your advice and I am going to buy a noise cancelling headphone. Based on your answer, the volume loudness of the music/sound that is playing is more important than the type of frequencies it is made of, right? I kind of like fan noise sound, probably becouse I heard that sound since my childhood (I live in a sunny country).

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to what you are currently doing as 'wearing headphones playing fan noise'. That 'fan noise', do you mean that literally? As in, have you used a microophone to record the sound of a fan?

The reason I ask: in the past, when I needed to drown out noise, I used earphones, and the sound I used was white noise.

I downloaded a .wav file with white noise from somewhere, I did copy/paste in a sound editor (multiple times), that gave me a file of white noise of many minutes long. I played that file in a loop.

The purpose I had with that was to *drown out* the incoming noise to some extent. There is of course a big difference between noise cancelation, and trying to drown out one source of noise using another source of noise.

As you know, hammering noise doesn't have a discernable pitch, that indicates that the sound has a very wide spectrum, which makes it very hard to protect yourself against it.

If you start with a file of white noise you could maybe try the following: use a sound editor, and alter the distribution of frequencies. You probably don't need the high frequencies. The hammering noise that reaches you has already traveled some distance, and over distance sound loses high end first.

Other than that maybe you can tweak the distribution of frequencies in other ways, and try them to see if you can notice a difference in performance for drowning out hammering noise.

About noise cancelation technology:

Noise cancelation works best when the noise source is highly repetitive (which unfortunately hammering isn't) The best use case is the noise of an engine (car engine, boat engine, airplane engine) that is running at constant RPM (rotations per minute)

High end noise cancelation involves some level of investigation of the incoming sound, and when the incoming sound is highly repetitive the algorithm can tweak the countersound that it produces, to optimize the cancelation.

It may be that noise cancelation has developed to a point where it can also handle highly irregular sound, I don't know.

Still, in the case of hammering noise I don't expect too much from noise cancellation.